# Which Ubuntu version has the 4.0.6 kernel which supports L2TP VPN?

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, vpn

I think kernel 4.0.6 came with l2tp vpn support which is a must for me (it's present in another distro).

Is there any Xubuntu version that officially supports it or comes with this kernel?

I know that there is an l2tp client 3rd party application but I haven't been able to make a successful connection with it to privatevpnaccess.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no stable Ubuntu release with kernel 4.x yet.

There are l2tp modules in current Ubuntu kernels for a long time.

It looks like you misunderstood something regarding l2tp. You will need a user space application (xl2tpd or openl2tpd) to use l2tp protocol.

These application use kernel modules. I am now writing this connected with l2tp to ISP.

Comment: according to ubuntu apps, xl2tp is not supported in 14.x

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xl2tpd/

Comment: @ErkanA It is supported. And it is in main repositories. I use it. 14.04 has 1.3.6+dfsg-1

Comment: @ErkanA look [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xl2tpd&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)

Comment: Another good one!

Comment: ok, i will try with 14.04.2 now

Comment: Excuse me but I have installed 14.04.2 with all updates, also installed xl2tpd. Is xl2tpd a server app?

Comment: @ErkanA You can set up it as a client or a server.

Comment: @Pilot6 Any way of knowing or predicting when kernel 4.x will get into the standard update pipeline?

Comment: @aidan Kernel 4+ will be installed in Ubuntu 15.10.